# Azure Blob Indexer metadata fields, encoding

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using the Preview auf the Azure Search Blob Indexer. All of the information that should be indexed is contained in the blob metadata. While testing things out I ran into a problem with metadata encoding:

As Azure Storage Blobs Metadata values have to be valid HTTP Header values, we have to encode non-ASCII characters (see [Invalid character exception when adding Metadata to a CloudBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899461/invalid-character-exception-when-adding-metadata-to-a-cloudblob)). The standard encoding for http header values, if i researched correctly, is Mime Header Encoding (as stated in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt).

When doing this, the indexer will contain encoded values, which is not great for searching. I have not found a way to make the blob indexer decode those values for the index fields, as the metadata fields are added verbatim (Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage/#ContentSpecificMetadata)

I know that Azure Blob Indexer is in Preview, but I am trying to document a few issues I am running into while trying to use Azure Search Blob Indexer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is on our radar. Please vote for this [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/10664853-add-ascii-friendly-string-decoder-to-indexer-field) to help us prioritize this work. 
We'll probably do this as a base-64 decoding capability because RFC2047 encoding is relatively obscure. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I could have seen that on UserVoice. Sorry & thank you!